# How to restrict current_user from adding more than 3 order_items to a order per time period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in Rails that has a specific sales model. I need to allow a user to add only 3 items to his order per 30 days. The 30 days counter should start upon adding the first order_item. Once 30 days expires, user would be able to add 3 orders. If 30 days didn't pass and for an example, user adds two order_items he would still be allowed to add one more order_item within 30 days.
So as well if user tries to add more then 3 items to show an error message and disregard saving of the order_items to current_user's order.

I have products, orders, order_items, users. I guess that I should add something to user model but I'm not sure what.

order_items_controller.rb

```
def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
  end
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :order
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :omniauthable, :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy, :new]
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for OrderItem.new,  html: {class: "add-to-cart"}, remote: true do |f| %>


        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :quantity, value: 1, min: 1 %>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure that you want to order this item for current month?'}, class: "btn btn-default black-background white" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add a `begin_date` and a `order_counter` to user model. Every time you add an order, look if the `begin_date` is more than 30 days ago, then set the `begin_date` to the actual date. If the begin_date is less than 30 days ago, increase the counter. And if the counter ist already 3 refuse the order.

You can add the columns to the user table by the command line argument

```
rails generate migration AddOrderCounterToUser
```

This will create a class in db/migrations:

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :begin_date, :date
    add_column :users, :order_counter, :integer 
  end
end
```

Add the additional attributes in your `UserController` to permit them in `user_params`.

Then change the create method in your `OrderItemController`

```
def create
  now = Date.today
  success = false
  if current_user.begin_date && ((now - 30) < current_user.begin_date)
     if current_user.order_counter >= 3
        # deal with the case that order should not be created, 
        # for example redirect.
     else
       current_user.order_counter += 1
       current_user.save
       success = true
     end
  else 
    current_user.order_counter = 1
    current_user.begin_date = now
    current_user.save
    success = true
  end
  if success
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
    end
  else 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "CREATION NOT POSSIBLE." } 
    end
  end
end
```

You can also put the checking code in a method in the user model, that would be cleaner.

Comment: I'm getting this error in my terminal when I try to add an item to a order: ArgumentError (comparison of Date with nil failed):
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:4:in `<'
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:4:in `create'

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a check whether begin_date is Nil (in this case you have to set begin_date, so go in the else case)

Comment: Have you added an error handling redirecting to another page?

Comment: I've updated the post that you do not need to redirect.

Comment: accept this answer OP. irene has all but written your code for you :P You should send a bottle of scotch as well.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you don't want to create an element in rails under certain circumstances, you should choose to handle the situation via validators.

You could take a nesting approaches here:
Nest your `OrderItem` routes under `Order` (you can find further information about nesting in the [Rails Guides about Nested Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources))

You should start by adding a new database column `first_item_added_at` to you `Order` model

```
rails generate migration AddFirstItemAddedAtToOrder

class AddFirstItemAddedAtToOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :first_item_added_at, :date
  end 
 end
```

When nesting, you would create a new `OrderItem` via the route

```
POST /orders/:id/order_items
```

Then, you have to add a validator to your `OrderItem` model

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :only_3_items_in_30_days


  private

  def only_3_items_in_30_days
    now = Date.new
    days_since_first = now - order.first_item_added_at

    if order.order_items.count > 2 && days_since_first < 30
      errors.add(:base, 'only 3 items in 30 days are allowed')
    end
    true      # this is to make sure the validation chain is not broken in case the check fails
  end
end
```

Now your controller only needs to create a new item and save it

```
def create
  @item = OrderItem.new(item_params)
  if @item.save
     render <whatever_you_want_to_render>
  else
    # @item will contain the errors set in the model's validator
    render <error_reaction>
  end
end

private

def item_params
  params.require(:order_item).permit(
    :attribute_1,
    :attribute_2,
    :order_id       # << this one is very important
  )
end
```

If you don't wish to nest `OrderItem`, than the model still remains the same, but your controller would look like:

```
def create
  @item = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)
  session[:order_id] = current_order.id

  if @item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
    end
  else
    render <handling for error>
  end 
end

private
def order_item_params
  base_params = params.require(:order_item)
                      .permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)
  base_params.merge(order: current_order)
 end
```

Please note, that I added `current_order.id` to your `order_item_params` method.

EDIT: replaced `order_id: current_order.id` by `order: current_order` to provide the relation to the new `OrderItem` before it is actually saved

Comment: I'm getting an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `first_item_added_at' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/order_item.rb:46:in `only_3_items_in_30_days'
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Comment: The reasons for that may depend on the controller solution you have chosen. Did you take the nested approach or the other one?

In both cases, the first question would be: is the order to which you add items already persisted when you call the `OrderItemsController`?

The second thing could be that I have mistaken the moment when the relation between two objects is generated by ActiveRecord. The solution here depends a little on the controller version you've chosen. I have updated the `order_item_params` method in second example.

Comment: I'm using second method you mentioned without nesting and I changed params but now this is the error: ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `current_order' for OrderItemsController:Class):
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:15:in `<class:OrderItemsController>'
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Cdu you pls update your initial post with your complete controller code? It seems, it does not inclide the method `current_order` anymore.